# Why system reboots the moment I use rm -r or rmdir to delete a directory under FreeBSD 10.2?

Tags: unix, freebsd, rm, rmdir

I have encountered a serious problem with rm command under FreeBSD 10.2.
Please use the link below to watch what I have recorded.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2qz5TY3D8M

In the current directory , there are two son directories (test1 & test2) both of which are empty. I want to delete them with rm -r .  It works fine to delete test2. But when I try to deal with test1, something horrible happens - the system reboots after showing something I don't understand.Later I also tried rmdir , the same thing shows too. I am not sure since when this has started. What kind of issue is this ? What can be done to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

The panic message shows that the parent directory had a link count of two. A directory's parent directory must have a link count of at least three. The references are the child directory, the parent directory and the parent directory's parent.

In your case something must have happened to get a link count of two. The most likely reason is that you have a filesystem in an unclean state that you have force mounted without running fsck.

If this is reproducible, then run `ls -la` to check the link count of `.` in the parent directory. Run `fsck` on your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Your filesystem is corrupted.  Assuming it's the root filesystem ("/"), you need to boot into single (press spacebar at loader prompt, then do "boot -s") and do "fsck /".